# C: Problem comparing equality of a value scanf-ed into an array with a constant

Tags: c

I'm absolutely new to C, and right now I am trying master the basics and have a problem reading data from and array populated via scanf. From what I have observed, I think the problem is with the scanf, but I'm not sure.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int array[11];
    printf("Write down your ID number!\n");
    scanf("%d", array);
    // trying to `printf(array)` here prints what seems like a random number
    if (array[0]=1) // this branch is always taken
    {
        printf("\nThis person is a male.");
    }
    else if (array[0]=2) // this branch is never taken
    {
        printf("\nThis person is a female.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected behaviour: The program's aim is to ask for an ID, and determine from the first number whether the given person is male (`1`) or female (`2`).

Actual behaviour:

- The array seems not to be filled properly.

  - This is checked via a printf(array) right after scanf, that results in random numbers.
- No matter what number is given as input, the program always says the person is male.

Comment: why u are taking array to store Id, just u can use integer

Comment: The id is probably longer and this is just part of the program. I guess the first digit of the id simply shows the gender.

Comment: You really need to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: You're scanning into `array`, not `array[currentIndex]`. Moreover, because `array[0] = 1` evaluates to non-zero, the if is ran and the person is printed as male. If there weren't for the `else` keyword, it'd be male/female.

Comment: @david-fong Considering the program does not work, it is absolutely and utterly off-topic at Code Review. Besides, this is a question from '13. A redirect would be much too late even if it had been correct.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody addressed the printf part of the question. When you `printf(array)`, you are printing `array` as a null-terminated string, which you did not intend to do. If you actually meant that you did `printf("%d", array)`, then you are printing the address of the array's first entry as an integer, which is also not what you meant to do. You probably meant to do `printf("%d", array[0])`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`if (array[0]=1)` should be `if (array[0]==1)`.

The same with `else if (array[0]=2)`.

Note that the expression of the assignment returns the **assigned value**, in this case `if (array[0]=1)` will be **always true**, since in if statements in C, [integers that are non-zero are truthy, and only the number zero is falsy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/if), that's why the code below the if-statement will be always executed if you don't change the `=` to `==`.

`=` is the assignment operator, you want to compare, not to assign. So you need `==`.

Another thing, if you want only one integer, why are you using array? You might want also to `scanf("%d", &array[0]);`

Comment: maybe he's trying to load in a series of numbers? essentially a for-loop wrapped scan.

Comment: Then he'll have to `scanf("%d %d ...", &array[0], &array[1], ...` (or with a loop).

Answer (score 5):

```
int main()
{
  int array[11];
  printf("Write down your ID number!\n");
  for(int i=0;i<id_length;i++)
  scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  if (array[0]==1)
  {
    printf("\nThis person is a male.");
  }
  else if (array[0]==2)
  {
    printf("\nThis person is a female.");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` conversion specifier will only convert *one* decimal integer. It doesn't know that you're passing an array, it can't modify its behavior based on that. The conversion specifier specifies the conversion.

There is no specifier for arrays, you have to do it explicitly. Here's an example with four conversions:

```
if(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3]) == 4)
  printf("got four numbers\n");
```

Note that this requires whitespace between the input numbers.

If the id is a single 11-digit number, it's best to treat as a string:

```
char id[12];

if(scanf("%11s", id) == 1)
{
  /* inspect the *character* in id[0], compare with '1' or '2' for instance. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
scanf("%d", &array[0]);
```

and use `==` for comparision instead of `=`

Comment: Ins't `&array[0]` the same as `array` ?

Comment: @zakinster no they aren't, you can check by using sizeof operator on both and see what you get.

Comment: @Fawad I meant in this context, i.e. *"as a parameter of scanf"* not *"in general"*. Once passed as a function parameter, [there will be no difference betwen `array` and `&array[0]`](https://ideone.com/YkI5a8). `&array[0]` is however better at expressing the programmer's intent in this context.