# Passing users input into an array

Tags: c

How can I receive a users input (A list of numbers separated by commas, eg. 3455, 564, 23435), and store it into an array?

I know ahead of time that I will be receiving 20 values from the user.

I have tried passing the users input "directly" into an array of size 20, but I get the error message: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
      'int (*)[10]' [-Wformat]

I have also looked at using the strtok function, although I do not want the delimiter (') still in the array.

Any ideas will be much appreciated,

thank you.

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far? See this [howto](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating examples to for you questions. Thanks!

Comment: looks like you are trying to use `scanf` to read in an array with only one statement.  Perhaps this question and answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16299727/1212725

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scanf()` function in order to achieve this.

The declaration of scanf function is as follows:

`int scanf(const char *format, ...)`

This means that while using `scanf()` function, you can specify the format of input you are receiving. Similar to `printf()` function, `scanf("%c",&character)`, for example can be used to get character input from user. `scanf()` function returns the number of successful reads.

*Note:* You can check whether `scanf()` function successfully read the intended data by stating for example:

```
if (scanf("%d",&intNum)==1){
    //all is ok, proceed
}
else{
    //EOF or conversion failure
}
```

Likewise, if you are scanning for multiple variables, you can use `if(scanf("%d %d",&intNum1,&intNum2)==2)`. Instead of `%c`, you can use any of the following(and more) in order to read and store different types of input.

Some of those:

`c` : character
  `d` : decimal integer
  `f` : float
  `o` : octal integer
  `s` : string of characters
  etc...

Furthermore; for example if you use `scanf("%d %f",&integerNum,&floatNum);`, you will be reading user's input in format **int float(int SPACE float)** and storing the values into integerNum and floatNum variables respectively. The **SPACE** character between `"%d %f"` is part of the format.

The second argument (`&character` in my case) is the address `scanf()` is going to store the value into. For more information about `scanf()` : [scanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm). You can use `scanf()` inside a loop to store user input into your array.

Here is a working sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int array[20];
    int i;
    printf("Enter value to be stored in array> ");
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        //printf("Enter value to be stored in array[%d]> ",i);
        scanf("%d,",&(array[i]));
        //scanf("%d,",(array+i));
    }
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        if (i==19){
            printf("%d\n",array[i]);
            //printf("%d\n",*(array+i));
        }
        else{
            printf("%d, ",array[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this example I used `scanf("%d,",&(array[i]));` since the format of the user input is going to be like this: **int,int,int,int,...(int COMMA int COMMA int COMMA ...)**.

Notice how `array` returns the address of the first element of the array.
By using pointers, you could rewrite `scanf("%d,",&(array[i]));` as `scanf("%d,",(array+i));`.

You can use this code to store other kinds of data like `float` with minimal changes. For example, in order to use this to get float input from user;

1. Replace `int array[20]` with `float array[20]`
2. Replace `scanf("%d,",&(array[i]));` with `scanf("%f,",&(array[i]));`

Also do not forget to use the right formatting when printing the values in your array.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help. This is the first answer I'm posting on this site. Hope it's not too bad.

Comment: Very good effort on your first answer, but two improvements. `"%d %f"` will read "*any number of whitespace* `int` *any number of whitespace* `float`" (numeric *conversion specifiers* ignore leading whitespace), and most import, when using `scanf`, you must **always check the return** and handle three cases (1) the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF`; (2) a *matching* or *input* failure occurs and characters are left in the input buffer **unread**; and (3) the return matches the number of conversion specifiers -- indication a good conversion. New users need that information.

Comment: Thank you for additional information. I tried to keep my answer as simple as possible thinking op is very new to C. Should I update my answer with error checks?

Comment: "The SPACE character between `"%d %f"` is part of the format." mis-leads as `"%d%f"` will do the same.

Comment: Good answer. My one bit of feedback is that line breaks are rarely necessary in answers. I have taken most of them out, and broken the material into paragraphs instead.